# Ways to say the cashier is handling my bill/check in a restaurant?

Tags: word-choice

How do I say the cashier is calculating my bill in a restaurant? Can I say "The cashier is ring me up?" or "She's closing me out" or "He's ringing up my bill?" Is "ring up" only applied to grocery store situation?

Comment: Do you mean the wait staff calculating a bill before handing it to the customer and then the customer pays the waitperson? Or, the customer takes the untabulated bill up to the register to tabulate and then pay? Or, a waitperson tabulates the bill but then the customer takes the tabulated bill up to a separate register (cashier) to pay?

Comment: @StuW I mean the the wait staff calculating a bill before handing it to the customer and then the customer pays the waitperson, but is there any differences when it comes to the other 2 situations that you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ring (something) up** is frequently used. //  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ring+up+something) idiom/definition

> To record the amount of money owed to purchase something and add it
>   to the total.
>
> To record, especially **by means of a cash register**
>
> ring up a sale.
>
> ```
> To accomplish or achieve: rang up several consecutive victories.
>
> Baseball a. To call (a batter) out on strikes. Used of an umpire.  b.
> To strike out (a batter). Used of a pitcher.
> ```

As in:

> The guy behind the counter had already started ringing my groceries
>   up when I realized that I had forgotten to pick up eggs. Would you
>   mind ringing this croissant up first? It's for my son to eat.

To **ring one up** typically applies to situations where one approaches a check out with a cash register.  As for a restaurant, yes this applies if one eats and then proceeds to the ckeck out.  It can even apply if one eats, calls for  the waiter to "take my check" or "I will have my check please". Then one's check is being 'rung up'.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but does "ring one up" apply to restaurant situation?

Comment: edited answer to reflect your query ... my Ame experience.

Comment: @lbf In BrE we would say 'My bill is being rung up' rather than 'I am being rung up'. This is probably because to 'ring someone up' in BrE means to call them on the telephone.